# CiviCRM upgrade can't find core module in Drupal

Tags: drupal, upgrade, core

I'm trying to run a civicrm core module upgrade on a drupal 7 site. I follow all of the [posted instructions](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal7/), but when I run the civicrm/upgrade I get a white screen. When I return to the drupal modules the main civicrm core module is no longer listed. If I run the drupal upgrade script I get an error message that civicrm module is missing ... but I can see the module loaded on the server, with all it's files, in the correct location.

I shouldn't have to uninstall the module because I'm upgrading. I disabled all of the civi helper modules, but made sure to leave the main civicrm module enabled, but I still get the missing module message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any chance you left the old civi code around in a re-labelled folder?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's no longer listed and it says it can't be found, it's usually one of these two things:

- your files are uploaded into the wrong spot
- your files have the wrong permissions and/or user attached

Comment: I've double checked that as well. According to documentation provided on CiviCRM + Drupal 7 upgrade, I downloaded the new civicrm files, disabled the all civicrm related contrib modules (but left the main civicrm module enabled), deleted from sites/all/modules the older civicrm directory, copied the new civicrm directory into the new location, cleared cache and template items cache, and then run the upgrade for civicrm/upgrade .Once I run the upgrade nothing happens, but the page goes white and civicrm is no longer an option on my site admin menu and the module is no longer listed.

Comment: That's what makes it sound like it is a location, permission, or user attached issue - it's either not finding the files or is unable to access them based on your description.

Comment: Jenni is right - this sounds like a user permission issue.  Is it possible the files are owned by a different user than they were previously?

Comment: OK - I'll give it another go and see what I can find. Thank you for your help. As an added note, I did revert back to the original civicrm files and everything came back just fine. Same exact file location and permissions as I had for the newer files.